# Force a logging page to display with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am currently developing an application with Ionic and I am wondering what is the best way to have a login page to display as a popup when no user are logged.

I would like for the application to check for the current user at startup and whenever the user change page. If `user == null`, then it will display a login page. The app should be "locked" on the login page until the user is logged/create account. (I am using Parse.com JS to create/log user)

I currently have a `ion-header-bar` on top of the page and  was thinking that I could put all the logic of the `checkLogedUser() == null` within the `ng-controller` of the header.

However, if I use the `$scope.$on( "$ionicView.enter", ...` within the HeaderController it does not seem to trigger the `$ionicView.enter` when I change page. I have a controller for the header and one controller for each of my page, so I always have two controllers on the same page, I am not sure if that's causing the issue and the `$ionicView.enter` get triggered on the page controller instead of being triggered both on the header controller and on the page controller. Also, I was thinking this could be a cache issue but I am not sure how to deactivate the cache for the `HeaderController` as the header isn't declare in the `$stateProvider` as it is not a page in itself but just a `ion-header-bar` with a `ng-controller`.

Also, there might be a better way to do that, I have slightly tried to user a service but without any luck.

EDIT2 with working code:

I have put the $rootScope.$on part in the  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {...}) part. My ionic app.js starts like that :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', **'app.services'**])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, **authService**) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
       console.log("$rootScope => $stateChangeStart => " + toState.name || '');
        if (toState.data && angular.isObject(toState.data)) {
            if (toState.data.requireLogin && !authService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go("login");
            }
        }
    });

  });
})
```

Then create file app.services.js (the one from the plunker link)

Comment: Any feedback with my answer ?

Comment: I am still working on it ... It does look good but I just have trouble "injecting" the service within the $ionicPlatform !

Comment: If you add some info to your question or give me some clue I can try and help.

Comment: I have added some info, thank you :)

Comment: You have to inject your service `.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, authService) {}`

Comment: and your service must be declared in another file. did you check the plunker?

Comment: Yes, I am also looking at the plunker. I have the exact same app.service.js (included in my html file). I have set the .run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, authService) { ...} but I get Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: authServiceProvider <- authService

Comment: It might be cause you haven't added the reference to services.js in your html? Another thing to remember, all your modules must be built like this   `angular.module('app.services', [])` or `angular.module('app.controllers', [])` with square brackets, even if you're not referencing other modules.

Comment: Got it working !! thanks a lot ! I will edit with the working code.

Comment: Glad I've helped, batman. AngularJs can be a little bit tricky at first but then things start to make sense. An upvote is always very welcome :-) Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of options there and it's only a matter of what you prefer in terms of implementation.

First of all, why would you want to have a controller for your header? I don't think you need that.
The best approach - for me - is to use a service where you can implement your logic for checking the user, logging-in and out or, eventually, interacting with another authentication service.

Since you want to check if the user is logged-in and force it to login before he/she can visit a protected area (view) the best option is to manage the states.

What you can do is to attach some custom data to your state object ([ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects)) so that you can check if the view needs a valid user:

```
$stateProvider

      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'homeController',
        data: {
          requireLogin: true
        }
      })

      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'loginController',
        data: {
          requireLogin: false
        }
    });
```

As you can see I have 2 states here and I've extended them with some custom info: `data: {requireLogin: true/false }`

Now I can use the [event](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) `stateChangeStart` to do some checking:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (toState.data && angular.isObject(toState.data)) {
        if (toState.data.requireLogin && !authService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go("login");
        }
    }
});
```

This even is fire every time the state changes. 
Here you can if the state you're going to (toState) has the extended data and if the new state requires a login. Of course you need to check if the user is logged-in already.

If the user is not logged-in you can redirect to a login page `$state.go("login");`.

This last check can be done using a service:

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.services', [])
    .factory('authService', authService);

  authService.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];

  /* @ngInject */
  function authService($q, $http) {

    var service = {
      userLoggedIn: false,
      isUserLoggedIn: isUserLoggedIn,
      login: login,
      logout: logout
    };

    return (service);

    function isUserLoggedIn() {
      return this.userLoggedIn;
    }

    function login(username, password) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      this.userLoggedIn = true;

      deferred.resolve(true);

      return deferred.promise;
    }

    function logout() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      this.userLoggedIn = false;

      deferred.resolve(true);

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
})();
```

Don't be scared about the style. I use some best practices you can find [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#services).

This service layer has got a member (property) `userLoggedIn` and three methods:

- isUserLoggedIn (check if the user is logged-in)
- login (do the login)
- logout (do the logout)

`login` and `logout` don't do much here; just return a boolean through a promise. I've used a promise even if I didn't need it cause - I guess - in your implementation you're going to interact with an remote API using `$http` or some other service layer which might work with promises.

With this code here your app will be able to check if the user is authenticated and redirect it to a login page.
Now we need a view for the login:

```
<ion-view view-title="Autenticazione" cache-view="false">
    <ion-content scroll="false" padding="false">
        <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="login(user)" novalidate>
            <div class="list">
                <div class="item item-divider">Utente</div>
                <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label" ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : loginForm.username.$invalid && !loginForm.username.$pristine, 'no-errors' : loginForm.username.$valid}">
                    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username" required ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength='100' />
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label" ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : loginForm.password.$invalid && !loginForm.password.$pristine, 'no-errors' : loginForm.password.$valid}">
                    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="user.password" required ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="100" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="padding">
                <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

There's nothing fancy here. It's just a simple form which does some validation checks before submitting the data to a login controller `ng-submit="login(user)"`.

This would be the controller:

```
.controller('loginController', function($scope, $state, $ionicHistory, authService) {

      $scope.user = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
      };

      $scope.login = function(loginUser)
      {
        authService.login(loginUser.username, loginUser.password)
          .then(function(result){
            alert('login successfull.');

            $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
            $ionicHistory.clearCache();
            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true, disableAnimate: true, historyRoot: true });

            $state.go('home');
          })
          .catch(function(reason){
            alert(reason);
          })
          .finally(function(){
              // do something.
          });
      };
});
```

the login controller defines an object user:

```
$scope.user = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
};
```

which I pass to my view and read later for validation.
The login method interacts with the service `authService` to execute the login method.
Since the method login in the service returns a promise I need to check the result. I can to that using `.then`. 
If the login is successful I just clear the cache and go to the home page setting that page as the root in the history:

```
.then(function(result){
    alert('login successfull.');

    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true, disableAnimate: true, historyRoot: true });

    $state.go('home');
})
```

Now the event `stateChangeStart` should be triggered again but this time the service should return when asked if the user is logged in `authService.isUserLoggedIn()`.

Probably the easiest way to understand how things work is to dig into the code running this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RWStEAcKAxO2RtZVb1bG?p=preview).